# Trying to find if a number exists with total of X positive factors out of which there are K distinct prime factors

Tags: python, python-3.x

If the number is of the form of a^b*c^d*e^f where a,c and e are prime numbers then total number of factors are (b+1)(d+1)(f+1).

I approached the problem in the following way-
If there are more than or equal to K prime factors of X then it is possible otherwise it is not.

I am getting a TLE error.

We have to print 1 if such a number exists and 0 if not.

---

```
import math
T = int(input())
for _ in range(0,T):
flag = 0
X,K = map(int,input().split())
if K == 0:
    if X == 1:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
elif K == 1:
    if X >= 2:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
elif K>=2:
    if X >= 2**K:
        count = 0
        while ((X % 2 > 0) == False):
            X >>= 1
            count += 1
            K = K-1
        #if (count > 0):
        #   count1 = count
        for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(X)) + 1):
            while (X % i == 0):
                X = int(X / i)
                K = K-1
            #if (count > count1):
            #   n.append(count)
            i += 2
        if (X > 2):
            K = K-1
        if K <= 0:
            print(1)
        else:
            print(0)
    else:
        print(0) ***
```

The constraints are- 
T<= 10^3
X,K <= 10^9

Any way to reduce the runtime?

Comment: T is the total number of test cases. I edited my post to correct the mistake you pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simpler recursive function with a Counter object to determine if there are at least K prime factors forming X.

This function will not only give you the list of prime factors but will also provide a count (power) of each prime. The sum of these counts is the maximum number of factors of X.

```
from collections import Counter 
def primeFactors(N):
    for f in range(1,int(N**0.5)+1,2): # stepping by 2 gives a 30% speed-up
        if f==1: f=2   
        if N%f==0:
            return Counter([f]) + primeFactors(N//f)
    return Counter([N])

X = 368640000
K = 21
result = 1 if sum(primeFactors(X).values())>=K else 0

print(result) # 1
```

*This runs in 0.16 seconds for 1000 random test cases on my laptop.  The worst case scenario takes 1.06 seconds if all 1000 test cases have X=999999937 (largest prime below 10^9)*

[EDIT] here is a variant of the solution using a simple dictionary. It is a bit more code but has the same performance as with the counter object

```
def primeFactors(N):
    for f in range(1,int(N**0.5)+1,2):
        if f==1: f = 2
        if N%f==0:
            result    = primeFactors(N//f)
            result[f] = result.get(f,0)+1
            return result
    return {N:1}
```

[EDIT2] Here is an optimized version of your original code.

These are the optimizations I did:

- Removed unnecessary logic and conditions (e.g. X>=2**K)
- Fixed the 2 by 2 stepping range that didn't work (having i+=2 inside the loop does not make it step by 2).
- Made the factor loop break when the squared factor (i) went beyond the remaining X (instead of always looping all the way to the square root of the original X).
- Also broke the loop when the K target is reached.
- Removed the special code to process prime=2.
- Made sure to use only integer arithmetic (// instead of /)
- Eliminated the square root calculation (using i x i < X to break the loop).

...

```
def OP(X,K):
    if K == 0: return int(X==1)
    if K == 1: return int(X>=2)
    for i in range(1,X,2):  # stride by two until break
        if i==1: i=2        # handle first prime (2)
        while not X % i:    # reduce X and K for prime factors
            X //= i            # X becomes other factor in X = i * X'
            K  -= 1            # one less prime factor to find
        if K<1 or i*i>X:
            break           # break when max prime reached (or K primes)
    return int(K<=0)
```

With these changes, the calculation perform almost as fast as the primeFactors() function (roughly 50% slower).

Comment: Can you please explain what function the counter statement performs? I am relatively new to python so am not familiar with the built-ins. Is there any way to execute it within the time limit without using the counter object?

Comment: The Counter object is a variant of a dictionary.  It is in the form {Key:count} and overrides a few arithmetic operators to combine these dictionaries together by adding/subtracting counts of common keys.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help. Turns out that my the X>= 2**K statement was causing the TLE in my program. Removed it and it worked just fine. Thanks again